# I found no \citation \bibdata \bibstyle commands in error in TexMaker or Biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, texmaker, biber

Well, this actually is an answer...

I had this problem recently on Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty) and it got me a little bit irritated, so I'm posting this answer; I saw similar questions but not with these specifics.

If, let's say, you decided to use sharelatex or overleaf for a group project and it was compiling like a charm using biblatex and biber with

`\usepackage[backend=biber,...,...]{biblatex}`

but suddenly, when you downloaded the .zip and tried to compile it again on Texmaker it "couldn't find \citation \bibdata \bibstyle commands",and you happen to have installed tex-live... AND you're like "oh boy... i guess i'll keep doing it online" (not with these specific words i imagine), this might be for you... (see answer)

Comment: See also [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864) as well as [Question mark instead of citation number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864). Note that in newer versions of `biblatex`, Biber is the default back-end, so if you want BibTeX (why would you?) you need to request it via `backend=bibtex`. Note that sometimes the versions of TeX packages shipped by Ubuntu are a bit outdated, so you might note differences between the output you get on your machine and the online editors.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what you gotta do:

Terminal:
    `sudo apt-get install biber` (install it)

Go to Texmaker > Options > Configure

At the "Commands" section (the one that appears), in the field named "Bib(la)tex" change the content (probably `bibtex %.aux`) to  `biber %` and try it again.

*** To make things easier, you might, as  well, go to the "Compile" section, and set the quick compile to PdfLaTeX + Bib(la)tex + PdfLaTeX (x2) + View Pdf.

Then click OK and try to compile it again with F1 (if you did the "***" part). I'm inclined to think it'll do the work.

If someone has another answer to this problem, I'm eager to know it xD

---

And yes, you should consider learning vim or emacs for the next project and profit from the experience by using their bindings on sharelatex (or overleaf).

---

you may compile it at the terminal as well:

`pdflatex <myfile>
 biber <myfile>
 pdflatex <myfile>`